# Loading components on startup, with timing measurements

Tags: c#, benchmarking

I was just wondering, is there a way to load these better and log the times they each took? It seems like a headache having to write about 90+ stopwatches, which is what I will have to do as I have about 100 of these to load.

```
// PacketManager
var packetManagerStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
_packetManager = new PacketManager();
packetManagerStopwatch.Stop();
Logger.Trace("Loaded PacketManager [took " + packetManagerStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms]");

// Achievements 
var achievementStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
_achievementManager = new AchievementManager();
achievementStopwatch.Stop();
Logger.Trace("Loaded Achievements [took " + achievementStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms]");

// Talents
var talentsStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
_talentTrackManager = new TalentTrackManager();
talentsStopwatch.Stop();
Logger.Trace("Loaded Talents [took " + talentsStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms]");

// Badges
var badgeStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
_badgeManager = new BadgeManager();
badgeStopwatch.Stop();
Logger.Trace("Loaded Badges [took " + badgeStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms]");

// ClientManager
var clientManagerStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
_clientManager = new GameClientManager();
clientManagerStopwatch.Stop();
Logger.Trace("Loaded GameClientManager [took " + clientManagerStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms]");

// ModerationManager
var moderationManagerStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
_moderationManager = new ModerationManager();
moderationManagerStopwatch.Stop();
Logger.Trace("Loaded ModerationManager [took " + moderationManagerStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms]");

// ItemDataManager
var itemManagerStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
_itemDataManager = new ItemDataManager();
itemManagerStopwatch.Stop();
Logger.Trace("Loaded ItemDataManager [took " + itemManagerStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms]");
```

Comment: Where is this code? In a constructor? Are the fields `readonly`? Can the constructor be parameterized? How close to the entry point is it? Who is the caller?

Comment: Why does your code have [so many Managers](https://blog.codinghorror.com/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager/)?

Comment: _I have about 100 of these to load_ - There's something terribly wrong with your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a generic method like this:

```
static T createInstanceOf<T>() where T : new() {
  var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
  T result = new T();
  stopwatch.Stop();
  Logger.Trace("Loaded "+ result.GetType().Name +" [took " + packetManagerStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms]");
  return result;
}
```

Now you can simply use it like this:

```
_packetManager = createInstanceOf<PacketManager>();
_achievementManager = createInstanceOf<AchievementManager>();
_talentTrackManager = createInstanceOf<TalentTrackManager>();
_badgeManager = createInstanceOf<BadgeManager>();
// and so on...
```

Comment: I don't know where you're getting `Stopwatch.StartNew()`, but if it has `stopwatch.Pause()` and `stopwatch.Resume()` methods, it's better to create only one instance of it. The way you're doing now is creating a lot of work for the garbage collector.

Comment: I like the general idea but (a) methods in c# are PascalCase, and (b) I don't like that it's doing all that extra stuff in a method that's only supposed to create an instance of something. Maybe for this case it's ok, but I think for production use you wouldn't be doing all this timing and tracing, so I'd wrap it in a decorator that calls the "create instance" method and times/logs it.

Comment: For production use I would use a profiler tool, I wouldn't roll my own implementation. How would you use a decorator?